# Rails - How do I display a post number, both in a list of posts and on the individual post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently building an app in which people add a project then add updates to the project. I want to number these updates, for example:

Update 1, Update 2, etc...

There is a list view but also an individual view where it will say the update number at the top.

I've found various index counting solutions to use when looping through the records to create the list, but I'm stuck with how to then display the update number on the individual view.

Should I even be storing the update number with the record in the database?

Relavent parts of my schema:

```
create_table "projects", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "image"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "projects", ["user_id"], :name => "index_projects_on_user_id"

  create_table "updates", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text",       :limit => 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
    t.integer  "project_id"
  end

  add_index "updates", ["project_id"], :name => "index_updates_on_project_id"
```

Comment: could you post the relevant parts of your schema?

Comment: Edited to add the bits of the schema about projects and updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, you have an Update model which contains all updates. So the ids of them are not in a sequence within a single project.

I think a simple and safe solution is to add an update_number field for this model.

Then you create a method to save the update number every time you create a new Update record, say +1 at the last update within this project.

**Add for question in comment about deletion**

I've considered this situation but I thought you should never delete an update(because it's an update, no matter right or wrong), so I did not say it. However, with this extra field solution, you can easily rebuild the index. Just write a method to rebuild the index, and hook it into any deletion of Update.

Side note: If I were you, I will set an Update as inactive instead of deleting it physically. Because your users are project team members, they should be responsible enough. Think about Git, it's very hard to change a commit once pushed to team or public.

Comment: Yep, that's correct. I think I'll add in that field then :)

EDIT:
Also, am I right in thinking the logic for the method would be something along the lines of finding the previous most recent update for a given project and getting its update_number, then adding 1 to that number and storing that in the new record?

Comment: yes, my method in mind is similar to that. May not be perfect but it should work.

Comment: Just realised that this may fall short if, for example, update number 3 of 5 was deleted. The numbering would skip from 2 to 4 then unless I wrote something that went and updated the rest of the records after deletion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column),or you can directly use `@project.updates.count`

Comment: This gives a count of updates, not individual update numbers.

Comment: Not sure if that's totally the right thing as I think that's just for getting a total? There's some useful stuff in that railscast that I hadn't found before and can use elsewhere in my app though :)

Answer (score 0):

You could order by created_at, and iterate in your view with each_with_index. This requires no schema change. You can also use [acts_as_list](https://github.com/rails/acts_as_list).

Answer (score 0):

Billy Chan has the best answer, but if you're looking for an alternative, you could look for your Update within the Updates for that project, and find its index.

```
@update = Update.find params[:id]
@update_number = Update.where(project_id: @update.project_id).order("created_at DESC").index(@update)
```

More long winded though and more queries etc. Better to have that logic stored in the DB.

Comment: This works really well for the individual update page where the number of queries is always the same. I just made the slight change of putting + 1 at the end as it starts at 0 by default. I just added this into my view.

    `<%= Update.where(project_id: @update.project_id).order("created_at ASC").index(@update) + 1 %>`

However, I will probably still go for Billy Chan's database method as I think I can potentially use the proposed update_number field in my URL too and make it more relavent than the ID that's currently in there :)

Comment: Oops, forgot the +1. and yep, I'd do that too.

Comment: Oh yea and I also changed DESC to ASC. Not sure if it was just my particular usage of the code that required that though..